# Return min value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. In each object there is a details property (array) with more than one object - for this example I am only showing one.

I am looking for the rating property in each details and looking to find minimum value (in this example 3.1) ... is there a simpler/cleaner way of achieving this?

```
const ratings = [{ id: 'ABC', details: [{ type: 'VALUE', rating: 9.5 }] }, { id: 'DEF', details: [{ type: 'VALUE', rating: 3.1 }] }, { id: 'GHI', details: [{ type: 'VALUE', rating: 4.5 }] }]
const ids = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
const array = []

ids.forEach(element => {
  const valueScore = ratings?.find(r => r.id === element)?.details?.find(c => c.type === 'VALUE')
  if (valueScore.rating) {
    array.push(valueScore.rating)
  }
})
console.log('MIN VALUE', Math.min(...array))
```

Comment: Instead of iterating over the ids and then using `find` why not just iterate once through `ratings`, also if your code works and you want feedback/suggestions you might want to look at the code review SE site

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` and then apply math.min to get minimum value:

```js
const ratings = [{ id: 'ABC', details: [{ type: 'VALUE', rating: 9.5 }] }, { id: 'DEF', details: [{ type: 'VALUE', rating: 3.1 },{ type: 'VALUE1', rating: 2.1 }] }, { id: 'GHI', details: [{ type: 'VALUE', rating: 4.5 }] }];

const ids = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']

console.log(Math.min(...ratings.flatMap(o=>
    ids.includes(o.id) ? o.details.flatMap(p=>
        p.type=='VALUE' ? p.rating : []) : [])));
```

Comment: I am looking for rating of type VALUE though. It's possible there would be another type (e.g. { type: 'TEST', rating: 4 } ... and I don't want to look at that

Comment: Thanks! Also, we need to check that the minimum rating is an id that is found in ids array ... if there is another entry in ratings such as XYZ, this shouldn't be included. can you modify?

Comment: @Michael that was a simple check in flatMap. Updated.

Comment: Thanks so much :) Simple and clean. I always forget about flatMap

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Why this method is preferred is, you are running the loop perfectly over each ratings item and also through each details array item.

```js
  ratings = [
    { id: "ABC", details: [{ type: "VALUE", rating: 9.5 }] },
    {
      id: "DEF",
      details: [{ type: "VALUE", rating: 3.1 }, { type: "VALUE1", rating: 2.1 }]
    },
    { id: "GHI", details: [{ type: "VALUE", rating: 4.5 }] }
  ];

  ids = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"];
    const detailsRatingArr = [];
    if (ratings.length === ids.length) {
      ratings.forEach(eachRating => {
        ids.forEach(eachId => {
          if (eachRating.id === eachId) {
            eachRating.details.forEach(eachDetail => {
              detailsRatingArr.push(eachDetail.rating);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
    console.log("DETAILS ARRAY ==>", detailsRatingArr);
    detailsRatingArr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    console.log("Minimum Rating ==>", detailsRatingArr[0]);
```